# Update a partially set entity with associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**The context**

I have an entity with both `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` associations. I received from the frontend an object in which only some properties are set (not the associations). The goal is to update the data of that entity in the database.

**The problem**

The received object is a detached entity, so when it's updated, the merge operation is called. Since the associations are not set, the `@ManyToMany` part is deleted but not the `@OneToMany` (because there is no cascade). One option would be to retrieve the entity from the database with the `@ManyToMany` associations loaded, then copy all properties from the frontend object to that entity and then merge, persist the object but I am not sure it's a best practice.

**The code**

Create a full object in the database

```
    Course hibernate = new Course();
    hibernate.setName("Hibernate");
    Course java = new Course();
    java.setName("Java");
    entityManager.persist(hibernate);
    entityManager.persist(java);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setName("White House");
    entityManager.persist(address);
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("Sydney");
    student.addAddress(address);
    student.addCourse(hibernate);
    student.addCourse(java);
    entityManager.persistAndFlush(student);
    entityManager.clear();

    Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
    Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
    Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
    Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
    Hibernate: insert into course (name, id) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into course (name, id) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into address (name, student_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into student (name, id) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: update address set name=?, student_id=? where id=?
    Hibernate: insert into student_course (students_id, courses_id) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into student_course (students_id, courses_id) values (?, ?)
```

Persist the object from the frontend

```
    Student partialStudent = new Student();
    partialStudent.setId(student.getId());
    partialStudent.setName("Sydney Updated");
    Student attachedPartialStudent = entityManager.merge(partialStudent);
    entityManager.persistAndFlush(attachedPartialStudent);
    entityManager.clear();
```

This part generates a DELETE SQL

```
    Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_41_0_, student0_.name as name2_41_0_ from student student0_ where student0_.id=?
    Hibernate: select courses0_.students_id as students1_42_0_, courses0_.courses_id as courses_2_42_0_, course1_.id as id1_13_1_, course1_.name as name2_13_1_ from student_course courses0_ inner join course course1_ on courses0_.courses_id=course1_.id where courses0_.students_id=?
    Hibernate: update student set name=? where id=?
    Hibernate: delete from student_course where students_id=?
```

Student entity:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course")
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
        course.getStudents().add(this);
    }

    public void removeCourse(Course course) {
        courses.remove(course);
        course.getStudents().remove(this);
    }

    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
        addresses.add(address);
        address.setStudent(this);
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        addresses.remove(address);
        address.setStudent(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Student)) return false;
        Student student = (Student) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, student.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Course entity:

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        student.getCourses().add(this);
    }

    public void removeStudent(Student student) {
        students.remove(student);
        student.getCourses().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Course)) return false;
        Course course = (Course) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, course.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Address entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Address)) return false;
        Address address = (Address) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, address.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The received object is a detached entity, so when it's updated, the merge operation is called. Since the associations are not set, the **@ManyToMany part is deleted** but not the @OneToMany (because there is no cascade).

As you have a detached entity, the normal use case is that you pass it to the frontend where some changes are made to the entity. When this modified entity instance comes back from the frontend and you call `entitymanager.merge()` operation it should not delete the associations from the database.

The case you're describing, i.e., the associations get deleted (regardless of cascading is set or not) can only happen if you set the association to `null` as

```
student.setCourses(null);
```

or if you created a new instance of `Student`, say `studentNew`, copied some fields of the original detached instance, and passed `studentNew` to the fronend. In this case, the `courses` attribute is `null` when `studentNew` is received from the frontend. If this happens you have two options:

- if you have the old detached instance around copy back the state of `studentNew` to it and merge that instance.
- Otherwise, you have to load the entity from the database using the ID and copy the changed state to the managed instance.